# A python error occurs everytime when completing the installation of parrot os

Tags: failed-installation, parrot-os

```
Boost.Python error in job "packages".
Command 'apt-get --purge -q -y remove live-boot live-boot-doc live-boot-initramfs-tools live-config live-config-doc live-config-systemd live-tools calamares calamares-settings-parrot' returned non-zero exit status 100.
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
kded5 kio kpackagetool5 libboost-python1.74.0 libhfstospell11 libkf5archive5
libkf5attica5 libkf5completion-data libkf5completion5 libkf5doctools5

File "<string>", line 58, in <module>
```

I've tried 5 times at different times installing parrot os but it stucks at %77 and gives that error.